# Prove that $w$ is a weak solution, basic questions.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have this problem:
\begin{equation} 
\begin{cases} \Delta\:g+ \lambda \:g=0\quad {\rm in}\;D  \\ g=0\quad {\rm on} \; \partial D.\end{cases}
 \end{equation}
The domain $D$ is made by two triangles ${T}_1$ and ${T}_1$ with a common edge $L$.

I have found a function $u$ which is $0$ on every edge of ${T}_1$ different from $L$ and   such that $\Delta\:u+ \lambda \:u=0$ in ${T}_1$. Then, similarly, I 
 have found a function $v$ which is $0$ on every edge of ${T}_2$ different from $L$ and   such that $\Delta\:v+ \lambda \:v=0$ in ${T}_2$.

Then I prove that the eigenfunctions $u$ and $v$ fit toghether smoothly (${C}^1$) along their common interface $L$ and I call $w$ the function defined on $D$, which is $u$ on ${T}_1$ and $v$ on ${T}_2$.

I have now to prove that $w$ is a weak solution of the starting problem. I've just begun studying PDE and I don't kwow well how to proceed.
Is this the condition that I have to verify:
 \begin{equation*}
 \int_{D}{\bigtriangledown w\cdot\bigtriangledown \phi\: dx}=\lambda\:\int_{D}{w\:\phi dx} \quad{\rm for\; all\;\phi\in{C}_0^\infty  }\quad?
 \end{equation*}
Does  this condition come directly from the definition of weak solution?

In order to prove that $w$ is a weak solution I have thought to write the integral at the first member in this way: $\int_{{T}_1\bigcap supp(\phi)}{\dots}+\int_{{T}_2\bigcap supp(\phi)}{\dots}$ then to use the following identity: $\bigtriangledown w\cdot \bigtriangledown \phi=div(\phi\:\bigtriangledown w)-\phi\:\bigtriangleup w$   and the divergence theorem, but I can't prove the condition of weak solution. How can I prove this?
Thanks for the help!